# SMART attribute CRC error count raw values high + errors logged, time to replace drive?

Tags: raid, hardware, hard-drive, smart

I have 2x Hitachi Deskstar P7K500 about a year old in RAID 1, md0 is boot and md1 is used by LVM.

Just recently I got a warning in X (FC11) that there are one or more disks failing.

I looked at the SMART attributes and I have errors on both drives:

/dev/sda errors logged: 140, UltraDMA CRC error count raw value: 500, relocated sector count: 0
/dev/sdb errors logged: 900, UltraDMA CRC error count raw value: 8700, relocated sector count: 1

So I think I should be replacing sdb soon however should I also replace sda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's on both drives chances are it's probably more related to the sata cable/sata controller than the drives. I would try different cables, running them different ways around stuff that might cause interference, etc. It also could that there's a software bug.

While it is certainly possible for both drives to be experience the exact same error at the exact same time, it's extremely unlikely and very suspect.

p.s. before you take my advice that there's probably nothing wrong with your drives, make sure that you have backups! always have backups.